# scons: how to extract archives depending on timestamps

Tags: scons

My project uses external packages. These packages are distributed in tarball and their contents is extracted when the tarballs are updated.

For example, I use boost. The corresponding external package is boost.tar.bz2. This package contains the header files and libraries. What I would like to do is to automatically extract the contents of this archive with scons when the tarball is updated.

I can achieve this with a Makefile using a "timestamp file". When the tarball is newer than the timestamp file, the archive is automatically extracted:

```
all: external-packages

external-packages: boost xml2

boost: .boost-timestamp

xml2: .xml2-timestamp

.boost-timestamp: boost.tar.bz2
    @echo updating boost externals
    @tar xjf boost.tar.bz2
    @touch .boost-timestamp


.xml2-timestamp: xml2.tar.bz2
    @echo updating xml2 externals
    @tar xjf xml2.tar.bz2
    @touch .xml2-timestamp

clean:
    rm -rf .*-timestamp boost xml2
```

How can I achieve the same with scons?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to have a look at [the untar builder](http://scons.org/wiki/UnTarBuilder).

After you add the addition of the builder function/emitter in your site_scons folder your scons file might look like this:

```
env = Environment()
env..Append(BUILDERS = {'UnTar' : unTarBuilder})

external_package = "packages/boost.tar.bz2"
archive = env.UnTar(source=external_package)
```

You should however note that the untar builder doesn't take directories into the emitter, and thus does not delete these on a `clean`

The point with this builder is the *emitter* it will make sure that SCons knows that it can create the headers, so whenever something depends on them (someone include them) it will launch the untar builder whenever the tar file has changed.

Comment: My problem is not the unpacking of the archive. What I want to achieve is to unpack the archive BEFORE doing any other task.
I've found a solution: create a "start" task, make this "start" task depending on all unpacking tasks, and all other tasks depending on this "start" task. But it is very tedious to implement (my project is very large and has many tasks) and it doesn't work when doing "parallel" build (scons --jobs 4).

Comment: With scons you do not think about before and after, it is resolved by dependencies. If anything depends on a file which will be unpacked, the unpacking will be done before. So using UnTar will make sure that the dependency graph is correct so you won't have to worry about before or after.

Comment: @SergeWeinstock I have added a paragraph in my answer to point out this detail.